# Multiple hyperlink styling

Tags: html, css

Does multiple hyperlink styling still work these days?

The way I used to do it was like

```
.linkStyle2 a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.linkStyle2 a:link {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.linkStyle2 a:visited {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.linkStyle2 a:hover {
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.linkStyle2 a:active {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>


<span class="linkStyle2">

<a href="test.html">test link one</a>

</span>
```

It doesn't seem to work any more though.. even when inserting them as just classes into the hyperlinks.. it's really weird.

Comment: you're trying to apply the styles to the descendant a tag of the parent with class linkStyle2? because thats what its reading.

Comment: That should work fine...can you show a full example where it's not working?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cFpEP/
Is working fine, you must have other css styles conflicting. (Also in your question you are missing a starting <style> but that might just be a copy/paste error).

Comment: Sorry guys, I cut a lot of the jargon out so that it was easy enough to view.

I think I may have just solved this myself.. the answer: when I transferred to cloud hosting (last month) it mashed a lot of my coding together, for example lines where merged into one and some characters where reverted into different ANSI characters. The result was distorting the coding for the style tag:

<style type=â€text/cssâ€>

Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

In your case:
.linkStyle2 a {
   color: #999;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.linkStyle2 a:visited{
   color: #666;
}
.linkStyle2 a:hover{
   color: #CCC;
}

Answer (score 0):

Corrupt ANSI characters was reverting the style tag into:

```
<style type=â€text/cssâ€>
```